# PHP Mailgun wrong link in href

Tags: php, mailgun

I'm sending an activation email to newly registered users on my page.
The mail arrives like it should and everything but I have on problem.

The variable that is passed to the email template is used 2 times.

First time on the button that activates you account:

```
   <a style="padding: 10px 20px; background-color: #A3D900; color: #ffffff;" href="<?php echo $activate_url; ?>"><b><?php echo __('Activate') ?></b></a>
```

And the second time under the button in normal text:

```
<p style="color:#333;">
    <?php echo $activate_url; ?>
</p>
```

The link is properly added only the second time. The first on (the button href) links to the email itself (email.mydomain.com/....).

Why is this happening? How can I fix it?

Comment: Did you sorted it out ? I am having the same road block here.!

Comment: Sorry, kinda forgot about this question.
Answering now.

Answer (score 6):

There was a problem with mailgun. Mailgun was rewriting "hrefs" in my emails. I disabled the link-tracking and now it works fine. I don't really need link tracking, since I'm tracking the activation page already.

Comment: same problem here but the link-trancking disabled not work. did you do something else?

Answer (score 5):

This isn't a "problem" with Mailgun, it is the intended behavior when you have "Click Tracking" turned on for a domain.

Mailgun only changes URLs in `HREF` attributes on HTML parts, but changes URLs found everywhere in plaintext parts. I recently used this to show a new url to my users, but track their click-throughs: `please sign in and update your bookmark to our new web address <a href="http://this.will.be.rewritten.by.mailgun">http://this.will.NOT.be.rewritten.by.mailgun.org</a>`

The HTTP-based API allows you to send additional parameters to override the default open and/or click tracking settings for individual emails:

*o:tracking* - Toggles tracking on a per-message basis, see Tracking Messages for details. Pass **yes** or **no**.

*o:tracking-clicks* - Toggles clicks tracking on a per-message basis. Has higher priority than domain-level setting. Pass **yes**, **no** or **htmlonly**.

*o:tracking-opens* - Toggles opens tracking on a per-message basis. Has higher priority than domain-level setting. Pass **yes** or **no**.

Answer (score 1):

You can manage this using the Mailgun Control Panel by setting o:tracking-opens and/or o:tracking-clicks params to false. Also, changing the subdomain name can fix too.